# Переключение картинок по кнопке c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо что бы изображения переключались по нажатию кнопки.
Реализовал на imageBox и imageList, но imageList не позволяет делать разрешение изображения больше 256х256, а мне нужно значительно большее разрешение.
[image: Результат на imageBox и imageList]

Answer (score 1):

Создайте массив с изображениями, и по нажатию кнопки обращайтесь к нужному элементу.

```
public Image[] images=new Image[lenght];
//
.......
form.images[0] = global::WindowsFormsApplication6.Properties.Resources.picture1;
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать pictureBox для изображение больше чем 256х256 и нажатия кнопки будет изменять изображение

Comment: И где тут собственно ответ?